# google sitemap need all article in site or indexing latest only?

Tags: sitemap

Right now we have sitemap that produced dynamicly with around 400 products and submit it in google sitemap for index purpose. It's always hit the server resource to produce xml format for 400 products each time google sitemap crawl it. Since most product already indexed by google, I'm thingking to reduce the dynamic sitemap to only generate latest 50 products to save server resource.

I'm search an explanation about does google sitemap need all products to index regularly or just need the latest product that not indexed yet? Please advise me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put every page you want to be indexed in your sitemap. Even those pages which are old and already included in Google's index. Sitemaps aren't to tell search engines about new content. They're there to tell them about *all* of the content you want to be indexed.

Comment: So basicly you not recommend to produce xml dynamicly for gogole sitemap? instead, save it as file to save the resource. Am I right?

Comment: That depends on how large the file can get and how often it is being requested. If it isn't getting large or isn't requested often, creating it on demand. Otherwise a script create a static XML file during off-hours is a good idea to keep it from killing your server.